# Cancelling 1 Participant when Registered Multiple Participants

Tags: civievent, registration

So, I have what seems like a simple problem with no clear solution.

One of my users registered 4 contacts for an event (3 others and himself) and selected "pay later". When he went to pay hsi balance, he asked our administrative assistant to cancel one of the participants he registered, as they were no longer able to attend.

The registration was cancelled, but the amount due remains the same. The guy's paid for 3 of the 4 participants, which makes us even in our book, but he remains outstanding by $375 according to Civi.

What's the best course of action here? I want the total fee to reflect that he registered 3 participants, for $375 a piece.

Answer (score 1):

Just cancel their whole Event Registration and register it again for 3 participant - by this way you can match with amount paid in -

Please take an Back of the DB before trying out anything or create a test system for testing the issue - if this didn't work please let me know